# Jsoup isn't doing anything

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

I've got the permission set in my xml file and as far as I'm aware, I'm running the connection in a new thread. This program is very basic and I'm not getting anything.

All I want the program to do is read all the HTML code from the website.

I have my main class here:

```
package com.example.beem;

import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class Beamer extends Activity {

    Button checkbutton;
    TextView title;
    TextView status;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_beamer);

        checkbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checker);
        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);

        checkbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                status.setText("*click*");
                status.setText("loading");
                Callable <String> call = new threadWebRead();

                try {
                    String dub = call.call();
                    status.setText(dub);
                } catch(Exception e) {}         
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and my class which implements callable is here:

```
package com.example.beem;

import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import android.util.Log;

public class threadWebRead implements Callable{

    public String call() throws Exception {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Document doc = 'Jsoup.connect("http://www.spring8.or.jp/ext/ja/status/text.html").get();
        String title = doc.title();

        return title;
    }
}
```

I just wanted to see if `Jsoup` would work first of all before I work out how to read in all the HTML but nothing seems to happen. In fact, I've tried a lot of examples on here for reading HTML from a website and just none of them seem to work! Some people said  `Jsoup` makes things easier but I'm not having any luck.

Edit, infact, I don't think it actually succeeds in performing the connect line in the thread.

Some help would be much appreciated thank you.

[Logs](http://justpaste.it/1381) from the application.

Comment: I've been messing around and it seems that even though I'm reading the website with a new thread, something is still violating the UI thread.

Comment: Java Type Names should start with an upper case letter.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not related to the Jsoup.

```
try {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.spring8.or.jp/ext/ja/status/text.html").get();
    System.out.println(doc.title());
} catch (IOException e) {}
```

This prints the correct title: "SPring8 status"